# Is there a HARD counter to Riven?

Tags: league-of-legends

I find that Riven can do at least decently in every lane if played properly, is there actually someone who can counter her reliably?

Answer (score 4):

According to the Doombrew Riven guide on LoLPro, Renekton is the hardest champion for Riven, as he counters her ability to get in and out on small exchanges and can out-sustain her with Cull the Meek.

Link is as follows: [lolpro.com](http://www.lolpro.com/guides/riven/144-riven-guide-top-lane/tips-tricks-synergies-and-counters)

Answer (score 2):

There are no champs who can really be considered a HARD counter to Riven. Some champs that do well against her are Olaf, Garen, Renekton, Teemo, Nidalee and Kennen. Jax and Irelia can do well after a certain level as well.

I'd recommend goldfather8's guide on solomid.net to learn how to play or play against Riven. He goes into each matchup in detail, it'll help you understand how each champion can overcome Riven.

The main reason why there is no real hard counter to Riven is that she scales really well, has cc, has a shield for sustain, has damage from abilities and auto attacks (can't be hard countered by Teemo blind), and she has high mobility to escape bad situations.

Answer (score 1):

Teemo - Why?

1. He can kite ANYONE. If Riven tries to close the gap between you and her, you can outrun the hopping.
2. Teemo bullies any melee champion top lane, and even more if they rely on autos for their damage.

Its really easy too, just poke her like Teemo does, and kite her when she attempts to fight you. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Actually, Teemo's blinding dart range is equal to Riven's E>Q Combo which can close the gap pretty easily.

Comment: Not great advice, try matching Teemo up to Riven or Renekton and you will be crushed the second they hit level 2.

Comment: I agree with this. But: you have to poke occasionally to wear them down and don't extend. Riven (and Renekton) don't worry me as Teemo in top lane especially with, say, Haunting Guise for some HP. E is better than Q though

Answer (score 1):

Olaf, would be the hard counter if there was one, since once he hit level 6, He should never be killed by Riven at all. You just need to wait for riven to dash to harass you, and E her and walk away, till 6 when she dashes in, you can ult, when she stuns, and then hunt her down, since not factoring in flash, She has no way to stop you from killing her.

Comment: But considering Olaf's early game isn't very strong against Riven, I wouldn't say he's a hard counter. I've only barely won against most Rivens and that's relying on the extra heal from armor and 5 pots.

Comment: ^Agreed, he's a good lane partner to help counter Riven, but I wouldn't call Olaf a hard counter. It's very situational.

Answer (score 1):

Riven's health regen has been nerfed which makes poking and kiting a good counter if you have some range. That is, her sustain is lower now.

She can't go head to head after wearing her down. Even if you're playing Teemo top lane

Bottom lane, a typical ADC and support will poke and kite her out of lane.

[Patch notes](http://eune.leagueoflegends.com/news/preseason-balance-update-2-patch-notes)

Answer (score 0):

There is no "hard" counter to Riven, but some dudes to decent against her.

Olaf and Rumble are pretty much a skill match up, Olaf can beat Riven pretty hard if played correctly, so can Rumble if he gets a little help from his jungler.

Irelia looses early to Riven, but outscales her after 15 mins even if Riven has several kills more.

Malphite and Udyr to pretty good against Riven, and while Malph just outfarm/scales Riven, Udyr beats Riven if played correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I just smashed a Riven with Volibear. He has an monstrous early game, and that's what you need to shut her down.

Answer (score -2):

WW is a hard counter if you build first iteam frozen heart.
same on olaf (but only if you build frozen heart on olaf ww is stronger than olaf vs riven)
and jax is a strong counter as well